# Getting MismatchSenderId while sending fcm notification from php over ionic 3 app

Tags: php, ionic3

I have created android app (in ionic 3).

How to fix the error that I get trying to send fcm notification using php code on device registration id created by ionic app (I use server key from console.firebase.google.com ) :

```
{"multicast_id":****************,"success":0,"failure":1,
"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```